# How to set background to be fixed?

Tags: html, css

I am coding a template of a webpage and there is picture holder box but when this has to be updated by inserting a picture there I have to change the code. So is there any technique (without changing the code) so that I could show background color with width and height without placing picture and when needed then I can place there a picture. That is having width and height properties should show my picture placeholder i.e. background-color blue should show.

What I have tried...

```
<img src=" " alt=" " />
```

css...

```
img{background-color: blue; width: 200px; height: 200px;}
```

**My code is working in almost all browsers but it seems not to be working in mozilla.**

Comment: as your image doesn't have a source or any alt text it will not show up in firefox, you would be better putting the img in a div and styling that

Comment: having the alt text would show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `display:block` - that seems to fix it for Firefox 20.

```
img {
    display: block;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using just your code it appears to work? http://jsfiddle.net/n9bH3/

If you inspect the image element are there any overriding styles?

```
<img src="" alt="">
img{width:200px;height:200px;background-color:blue;}
```